# iPhone 7, iOS 10.1.1: Missing new wallpapers

Tags: iphone, ios, display, wallpaper

I just got the new iPhone 7 and the new wallpapers which I have seen on ads and Apple's website are missing.

**How to get them on my iPhone?**

Current OS: 10.1.1

I don't want to download them from the internet because of quality issue.
New wallpapers look like this.

[image: New wallpapers look like this:]

Comment: My iPhone has upgraded version of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These wallpapers are included with iOS 10.3, which is yet to be released publicly. Once this version of iOS is released to the public, you will be able to download it on your iPhone and select the wallpapers from the list in Settings.

Comment: Is the beta version of iOS 10.3 out? If yes, is it having new wallpapers?

Comment: @kshikhar Yes it is in beta, and yes it has the wallpapers you are looking for.